# How to find particular word from full text and make it hyperlink clickable with textview?

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, spannablestring

I am using textview and setting text which I get from json,

"This is our contact us page please call us"

the above text I am getting from server and it displays on 3rd recyclerview item, now what I am trying is in any listitem, if 'contact' word is there, I am trying to make it as hyperlink and want to make it clickable. but it is not working.

```
 String fulltext=brandList.get(position).getFAQAnswerText();
        String match="contact";

        if (fulltext.contains(match)) {
            System.out.println("Keyword matched the string" );
             ss = new SpannableString(fulltext);

            ss.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 6,
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            ss.setSpan(new URLSpan("tel:4155551212"), 13, 17,
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        }
        holder.tvans.setText(ss);
        holder.tvans.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
textView.setText("this is clickable text");
if (fulltext.contains("clickable")) {
    setClickableHighLightedText(textView, "clickable", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: do your stuff here 
        }
    });
}
```

Put this method in your Util class.

```
/**
 * use this method to set clickable highlighted a text in TextView
 *
 * @param tv              TextView or Edittext or Button or child of TextView class
 * @param textToHighlight Text to highlight
 */
public void setClickableHighLightedText(TextView tv, String textToHighlight, View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    String tvt = tv.getText().toString();
    int ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, 0);
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            if (onClickListener != null) onClickListener.onClick(textView);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setColor(tv.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            ds.setUnderlineText(true);
        }
    };
    SpannableString wordToSpan = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
    for (int ofs = 0; ofs < tvt.length() && ofe != -1; ofs = ofe + 1) {
        ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, ofs);
        if (ofe == -1)
            break;
        else {
            wordToSpan.setSpan(clickableSpan, ofe, ofe + textToHighlight.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            tv.setText(wordToSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

#### Update

- Change span color

  ```
      @Override
      public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
          super.updateDrawState(ds);
          ds.setColor(tv.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.spanColor));
      }
  ```
- Change highlight / onTouch color

  `textView.setHighlightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.onTouchColor));`

Comment: what is that yourTextView_Edittext_Button

Comment: `holder.tvans` in your case

Comment: First call `holder.tvans.setText(fullString);` then call my method.

Comment: can you please tell inside click listener what should i add?

Comment: You should see your app requirement, what they want to be done in onClick of that clickable text.

Comment: onClick code will execute when user click on that link. You will handle it as your need.

Comment: hi can you tell how to change text color with that?

Comment: please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712981/how-to-get-nonce-in-braintree-using-express-checkout

Comment: @Nilima No idea about this

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with SpannableString Class, Use Below method in your Activity or Utility

```
public static void makeLinks(TextView textView, String[] links, ClickableSpan[] clickableSpans) {
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
    for (int i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = clickableSpans[i];
        String link = links[i];

        int startIndexOfLink = textView.getText().toString().indexOf(link);
        spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, startIndexOfLink, startIndexOfLink + link.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

And you have to initialise it in your activity like this

```
Utility.makeLinks(textViewInsance, new String[]{"Your text which need to highlight and click event",}, new ClickableSpan[]{new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
        }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can find particular word from string by using:

  if (fullText.toLowerCase().indexOf(singleWord.toLowerCase()) > -1) {

  ```
  find = true;
  ```

  }

Make the text heyperlink by using JAVA code is:

```
    TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "<a href='http://www.kainaatsingha.com'> Kainaat Singha</a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

**Or Using XML**

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"
```